# Rails 3.2 and Paloma gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm facing a problem since yesterday. I try to use Paloma gem (v5) to organize my javascript. But I can't see any tutorial for this, in the current version. That's not the problem, there is a good wiki about it.

But I can't use it, and I don't know why...

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker-fr
//= require jquery.ui.monthpicker
//= require jquery.timepicker
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require redactor-rails
//= require magnific-popup
//= require selectize
//= require jquery-tablesorter
//= require jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter
//= require jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.widgets
//= require Chart
//= require paloma
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-multiselect

$(document).ready(function(){
  Paloma.start();
});
```

My coffeeScript (it's compatible):

```
console.log 'hello'

Paloma.controller 'Admin/RGrids', ->
 show_users: ->
  alert 'it works'
```

And my controller admin/r_grids_controller.rb

```
class Admin::RGridsController < AdminController
 layout 'admin'
 load_and_authorize_resource :r_grid

 respond_to(:html, :js)

 #show_users prints results in the retention grid for a USER
 #@return [hash] rgrid_for_user
 def show_users
  rgrid_scoped = RGrid.only_askers
  @show = RGridUtility.r_grid_vars(rgrid_scoped)
 end
```

'Hello' is displayed in the console, so the script is loaded. I tried many things like remove :js in respond_to, or use different way to call the action. 
Somebody can help me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Need to call Paloma.start() in my application.js with my function in r_grids.js inside the application.js